# Code Completion Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin-studio

Is there a way to enable automatic generation of a closing curly bracket when an opening curly bracket is typed in Xamarin Studio?

In other words, when I type `}`,in all the other IDE's I've used a `{` is automatically generated. That doesn't seem to be the case in Xamarin Studio.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can configure Xamarin Studio to automatically insert a closing curly brace when an opening curly brace is entered in Preferences - Text Editor - Behaviour - Insert matching brace.

Going the other way of entering a closing brace and having Xamarin Studio automatically insert an opening brace does not seem to work though.